# Python, using tkinter how to customize where classes of ui components are displayed?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am very new to python, and am currently trying to organize my tkinter app in a slightly different way. I'm trying to use classes to make the app more modular and be able to use methods in the class in multiple places in the app.  Here is the updated code that I have:

```
from tkinter import *


class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

        self.QUIT.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=RIGHT)

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createAnotherWidget()

        self.title_label.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.title_entry.pack(side=RIGHT)

    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi there, everyone!")

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.QUIT = Button(self)
        self.QUIT["text"] = "QUIT"
        self.QUIT["fg"]   = "red"
        self.QUIT["command"] =  self.quit

        self.hi_there = Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello",
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi


    def createAnotherWidget(self):
        self.title_label = Label(self)
        self.title_label["text"] = "Title: "
        self.title_entry = Entry(self)

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
        self.createAnotherWidget()

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

This runs without errors, but nothing shows in the window.  How can I customize where the code for these methods will be placed when rendered? For this example, I'm simply wanting the `createAnotherWidget` to display below the two buttons in `createWidgets`

Comment: If you are doing a tkinter application of any potential large scale (having multiple frames or having more than 4 widgets) I would look into how the .grid function works. Packing is very confusing to keep track of if you use it for your entire program.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have the caller be responsible for calling `pack` or `grid` on the individual widgets. This requires that you save references to the widgets somehow, such as attributes of the object.  You do this already for some widgets, but not for others. You need to be consistent.

Do this by moving the calls to `pack()` from the functions and into your `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.pack()
    self.createWidgets()
    self.createAnotherWidget()

    self.QUIT.pack(...)
    self.hi_there.pack(...)
    self.title_label.pack(...)
    self.title_entry.pack(...)
```

Of course, you'll need to modify `createAnotherWidget` to save references to the widgets.

The point being, *creating* widgets and *laying out widgets on the screen* are two separate problems that should be solved separately.

---

That being said, it's a bit unusual to have functions that create multiple widgets that are designed to be stitched together by some other function.

A more common pattern is for functions to create widgets that are related, and to manage the layout of the related widgets itself. That way the caller only has to worry about organizing the groups of widgets rather than a bunch of individual widgets.

For example, you might have one function that creates a toolbar. Another that creates the main area with scrollbars. Another function would create a footer. Another that creates a form with a bunch of label and entry widgets. Another one that creates a label/entry combination. And so on.

Comment: hi @Bryan Oakley, thanks for your help.  I have been working on it for a while and have gotten the code reorganized a bit.  I have updated in my question above what I currently have.  The window currently isn't showing anything.  Also, I don't understand how I can do what you mentioned in your last paragraph of this answer.  It sounds like the right way to do it for sure, but I'm unsure how to do it.  
Thanks again!

Comment: @Jaromij: You didn't do what is in the last half of my example.

Comment: Thanks for help.  I incorporated your advice and I learned a few other things from other research and got everything working.  Thanks for the help.